# jQuery Form Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a radio button as a click function:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
```

and I don't just want radio buttons, I want radio buttons with the class 'baby', or I could even do it by name if that's easier, searched google and I can't find anything :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this :

```
$("input[type=radio][class=baby]").click(function(){
```

Comment: Or perhaps even simpler: input[type=radio].baby

Comment: .baby is preferable. [class=baby] won't match class="baby somethingElse"

Answer (score 1):

You can have multplie selectors

```
$("input[type=radio]", ".baby").click(function(){}
```

[Here](http://www.pamaya.com/jquery-selectors-and-attribute-selectors-reference-and-examples/) you have nice examples

Answer (score 1):

Use the first selector to globally pick up your inputs and then filter using a second selector.

```
$("input[type=radio]").filter(".baby")
```